# Are "guard let" and "if let" different statements than "guard" and "if"?

Tags: swift, option-type, guard-statement

I know a guard statement can be used like this

```
guard let someConstant = someOptional() else {
    // ...
}
```

And I tried to do

```
struct MyStruct {
    let aString: String
    init?() {
        guard aString = optionalString() else { return }
    }
// ...
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

I assumed that the `let a = b` and `a = b` would somehow have a boolean value that was false when it failed, but are `guard let` and `guard` actually completely different?

Comment: An assignment statement `a = b` is *not* an expression in Swift, it does not have a value.

Comment: Don't mix up assignment (`=`) and equality (`==`) operator 

Comment: @MartinR I think that's what made me confused, doesn't guard and if need a boolean condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional binding in `if` statement works like that: it checks if given value has value and if it has it goes with this value to `if` block

```
if let constant = optional {
    constant
}
```

With optional binding in `guard` statement it checks if value exists and if does, it continue in current scope with variable / constant assigned in this scope

```
guard let constant = optional else { ... }
constant
```

So, for your initializer you need to assign constant, so you need to use `let` keyword and since your initalizer is optional, you need to return `nil` if initalization fails

```
guard let aString = optionalString() else { return nil }
self.aString = aString
```

Comment: Okay, but what I was confused about was that guard and if usually works with a boolean condition, and let constant = optional doesn't have a "return value" per se, does it?

Comment: @user3052786 Oh, then, simple explanation: optional binding (with let/var keyword) doesn’t return Boolean value directly and it first tries to assign constant/variable and it returns Boolean depending on if assigning succeeded or not.